# scp command not working inside expect in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, expect, scp

```
while [ $FileLine -le $FileListLines ];
                do
                        # extract each line from FileList
                        str=$(tail -n+$FileLine ../$FileList | head -n1)
                        hostpath=$username@$ip:$str
                        export hostpath ip
                        expect -c '
                                spawn bash -c "scp -pr $env(hostpath) $env(ip)"
                                expect {
                                        "(yes/no)?"{
                                                send "yes\r"
                                                expect "*?assword:*"
                                                send "password\r"
                                                }
                                        "*?assword:*"{
                                                send "password\r"
                                                }
                                        }
                                '
                        FileLine=$(( $FileLine + 1 ))
                done
```

The above is a part of a bash script. The `scp` command in the `expect` block is not working, that is, files from the remote machine are not getting copied to the local machine.

The same `scp` command with the `path` and `hostname` is working fine when being run from the terminal.

Comment: After sending password, wait for `eof` to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `expect eof` at the end of the expect code otherwise the `scp` process would be killed right after the password is sent. (Also add a space between the *pattern* and `{` in the `expect {}` block though not sure if that's a problem.)

```
expect -c '
    spawn bash -c "scp -pr $env(hostpath) $env(ip)"
    expect {
        "(yes/no)?" {
            send "yes\r"
            expect "*?assword:*"
            send "password\r"
        }
        "*?assword:*" {
            send "password\r"
        }
    }
    expect eof
'
```

#### UPDATE

Just tried and `"(yes/no)?"{` would not work. The space between the *pattern* and `{` is required so it should be `"(yes/no)?" {`.

Comment: tried `expect eof`..still not working. On running the script I do get to see the prompt awaiting for:
`Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?`
Then it moves on and creates a tar.gz which is outside the `while` loop, but the zipped file does not have any of the contents from the remote machine.
Just thinking, the variable `hostname` has a value like `username@someIP:/opt/var/log/*`
Does the character '*' for multiple files causing the issue?

Comment: i tried with `"(yes/no)?" {` and i get the below error:
`couldn't compile regular expression pattern: quantifier operand invalid
    while executing
"expect {
                                        -re "(yes/no)?" {
                                                send "yes\r"
                                                exp_continue
                 ..."
`

Comment: `-re` is not necessary here. Try `expect -d -c ...` and see what's wrong.

Comment: Removing the `-re` worked. Brilliant!!
But i did not get why the regular expression caused this issue

Comment: I guess you also added `-re` before `"*?assword:*"` but `"*?assword:*"` is not a valid RE pattern. `-re assword:` simply works.

Comment: One other suggestion: since you don't know how long the transfer will take, add `set timeout -1` before `expect eof`